# XPathEvaluator Not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, debugging, xpath, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

XPathEvaluator is not working in IE 9.
Can you please tell me the new method to replace this.

Thanks,
Hemant

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selectSingleNode` method of the [MSXML XPath API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846):

```
xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//book/author");
```